# Is it possible to define field types when adding fields and values to a document with C#?

Tags: c#, xamarin, google-cloud-firestore, xamarin.forms

Representing a document with a `Dictionary` is one way to add fields and values to it.
Is there any alternative which would also include defining the `Field type`?

For example a dictionary can be:

```
Dictionary<string, object> data = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { "field1", var1 },
            { "field2", var2 },
        };
```

Then by using `await doc.SetAsync(data);` the fields with their values will be added to the targeted document.

Is there a way though to define the types of the fields?

Comment: I added some code. Hope things are now clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set types explicitly in any language.  They types of any fields come from the types of the data you provide (in your case, `var1` and `var2`.  If you want to ensure the type of any field, then it's up to you to convert the values ahead of time.  For example, if you have a string, but you want a number field out of it, you will need to convert that string to a number before you give it to Firestore.

Comment: I want a string which represents a document path to get recognized as a `reference`. Of course it is recognized a simple string.

Comment: Then pass a DocumentRefrerence object that you create.